# create a table containing especific names of files selected from string in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to create 3 lists with the names of files starting with png, jpg and bmp. All files are images inside the directory tree: /year_month/year_month_day/ as you can see here:

./20160203/20160203_png01_test1.png.tmp

./20160203/20160203_jpg01_test2.jpg.tmp

./20160203/20160203_bmp01_test3.bmp.tmp

./20160204/20160204_png01_test1.png.tmp

./20160204/20160204_jpg01_test2.jpg.tmp

./20160204/20160204_bmp01_test3.bmp.tmp

./20160205/20160205_png01_test1.png.tmp

./20160205/20160205_jpg01_test2.jpg.tmp

./20160205/20160205_bmp01_test3.bmp.tmp

every list should contain the pictures name for every extension (jpg, bmp and png) for example list1 should have:

./20160203/20160203_png01_test1.png.tmp

./20160204/20160204_png01_test1.png.tmp

./20160205/20160205_png01_test1.png.tmp

list2 should have:

./20160203/20160203_jpg01_test2.jpg.tmp

./20160204/20160204_jpg01_test2.jpg.tmp

./20160205/20160205_jpg01_test2.jpg.tmp

and list3 the same but with bmp...

my code look like this:

```
workdir = '/home/user/201602/';
cd(workdir);

command =         ['find -name *test*.tmp'];
[status,cmdout] = system(command);
c =               strsplit(strtrim(cmdout));
n_files =         length(c);
format_id =       cell(n_files,1);

for ifile =1:n_files                    
      d = textscan(c{ifile},'%s%s', 'Delimiter','_');
      s1 = d{2}{:};
      format_id{ifile} = s1;
end

format_id = unique(format_id);
nformat = length(format_id);

for iformat = 1:nformat

     templist = [format_id{iformat} '.dat'];           
     fid = fopen(templist,'w');

     for ifiles =1:n_files
         fprintf(fid, '%6s\n', c{iformat});
     end

     fid  = fclose(fid);
end
```

I get the lists: png01.dat, jpg01.dat, and bmp01.dat which is fine, but in every list I have all the names of the pictures and not only the names with the respective extension. First I would like to make an "index" in order to select only the files with the respective extension (bmp jpg and png) and afterwards send them to a list. How could I do that?

I hope the problem is clear. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please remove the additional new lines throughout your question so that it looks easier to read. As a further suggestion: Have a look at the [`dir`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html)-command to replace `system`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the extensions like so:

```
extensions = {'.bmp', '.jpg', '.png'}
```

You can then access `extensions{1}`, which will return '.bmp'. By using a loop with an iterator `i` you can retrieve all `extensions{i}` until you reach the end of the list: `length(extensions)`.

To use as a selector:

```
command = [strcat('find -name *test*', extensions{1}, '.tmp')];
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Matt, consider the use of [`dir`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) function instead of `system` which is not portable:

```
workdir = '/home/user/201602/';
jpg_files = dir( fullfile(workdir, '*.jpg.tmp') );
png_files = dir( fullfile(workdir, '*.png.tmp') );
bmp_files = dir( fullfile(workdir, '*.bmp.tmp') );
```